# Bonus damage protection +x% on gear items in Age of Empires Online

Tags: age-of-empires-online

I understand most of the stats and what they do such as infantry armor +x%. Self explanatory. However, I am not sure what Bonus damage protection +x% means. Protection on top of armor or?? There is no ingame explanation for these things. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question, I'll do some testing on it later today, and see if I get some useful information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All units have some default values that determine their combat strength,lets say that some infantry unit has all stats on 10 and cavalry on 20 which makes cavalry stronger.If infantry is strong against cavalry they will have their default "cavalry bonus damage" set to 15.In that way they balance the game with default values and units.

The "bonus damage protection" is the default stat that reduces all incoming damage by some specific value,if default damage protection of infantry unit is 10 it will reduce all incoming damage by lets say 5 damage(unknown values), if you equip "+100% bonus damage protection" the damage protection of infantry would now be 20 and it would reduce incoming damage by 10.The specific "cavalry armor" and others will further reduce incoming damage by  value that corresponds to the attacker type.

Basicly that word "bonus" only confuses you it is "damage protection" + "armor protection" where armor protection will be different number depending on attacking type.

Comment: Interesting. The way I interpret it is the protection against damage from units that would normally deal bonus damage to you. E.g. If a sarissophoros hits a toxotes, it would deal bonus damage to it, but the damage is mitigated by the toxotes's bonus damage protection and the stat on the gear further enhances this mitigation. However when let's say a spearman hits the toxotes, the bonus damage protection doesn't come into play. That's just my interpretation, you could well be right too. I will accept your answer, but will test this tonight based on yours and my own theory :)